# Unity 5 3d Shop menu with prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can someone tell me how to implement other player prefabs as a shop menu LIKE THIS.

[image: shop]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that every pink rectangle is a prefab.

First, you need to understand the concept of [prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html).

Second, you need to know how to [instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) a prefab in run time.

Third, you need to [acces the properties](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html) for your new fresh instantiate game object so you can change the information of that prefab if you want, maybe you want some values to be 200 instead of 100, idk.

Finally, ther's no "right way" to achieve this, but I recommend you to use Unity UI and [scroll rect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUun2xW6FJ4) to achieve your goal.

If you have some time to experiment there will be a good idea to check out a [pooling](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling) system so you doesn't need to use so much memory at instantiate and destroying objects at runtime, you just reuse them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i dont no how to make thanks.
Do you know how to make this but with textures.

Comment: In fact you can use the same UI system I suggest before and switch the texture of your image changing his property on runtime.